# combine two update statements into one for different conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need a quick way to write an update query

```
UPDATE Content
SET Status = 1
WHERE Id in (SELECT userId from [User] where Location = 'US')
```

In this query itself, I want to SET Status = 0 WHERE Id NOT IN(SELECT userId from [User]).

Basically, I want to combine two updates into one.

```
UPDATE Content
SET Status = 1
WHERE Id in (SELECT userId from [User] where Location = 'US')

AND

UPDATE Content
SET Status = 0
WHERE Id NOT in(SELECT userId from [User] where Location = 'US')
```

,Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
update c
set Status = case when u.userId is not null then 1 else 0 end
from Content c
  left join [User] u on c.id = u.userId and u.Location = 'US'
```

For each `Content` row, we check if there is a corresponding US user and set `Status` accordingly.

Comment: Actually , in the Where clause I have many conditions. I will have to move those conditions inside Cases. It will work. Thanks